# node modules installed by npm install cannot run anywhere in command line

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

here is the terminal says:
`

```
$ npm root -g
/opt/node-v6.10.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules                                                          
$ ls /opt/node-v6.10.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules
babel-core/  cnpm/              gulp/      http-server/  webpack/
bower/       create-react-app/  gulp-cli/  npm/                                                      
$ http-server
http-server: command not found                                                       
$ gulp
No command 'gulp' found, did you mean:
 Command 'gslp' from package 'ghostscript' (main)
gulp: command not found                                                          
$ node -v
v6.10.0                                                         
$ npm -v
3.10.10
```

`
modules in /opt/node-v6.10.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules should be globally but when I call them in cmd, they just can't be found.  What's the possible problems?

PS. I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Thank you!

Comment: Where do you set the `$path` environment variable?  What is it set to?

Comment: do you mean this  `$ echo "$PATH"
/usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /sbin /bin /usr/games /usr/local/games /snap/bin
`

Comment: Yes, `$PATH`. Well, it doesn't include the node_modules bin directory, so the shell can't find the commands that go with the installed modules.  So again, where/how are you setting $PATH?  Are your user login scripts possibly overriding a system-wide value that would include the node_modules global bin?